# How to send mail in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Hi
I have written code to send mail in asp.net as follows:

```
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mailMessage.From = "xyz@gmail.com";
        mailMessage.To = "abc@gmail.com";
        mailMessage.Subject = "test";
        mailMessage.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Text;
        mailMessage.Body = "this is a test mail...";
        //mailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "localhost";
        SmtpMail.Send(mailMessage);
        lblStatus.Text = "Your mail was sent";
```

and my web.config file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                    <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
                    <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                </sectionGroup>
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
  <system.net>
    <mailsettings>
      <smtp deliverymethod="Network">
        <network host="localhost" port="25" defaultcredentials="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailsettings>
  </system.net>


  <appSettings>
    <add key="ConnectionString" value="server=W2K8SERVER;database=Quiz;uid=sa;pwd=Alpha#123"/>
    <add key="Delay" value="1800000"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="QuizConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=W2K8SERVER;Initial Catalog=Quiz;User ID=sa;Password=Alpha#123"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

    <system.web>
        <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
        -->
        <compilation debug="true">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
        <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
        <pages>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
            </compiler>
            <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
            </compiler>
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules>
            <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
            <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
            <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
            <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
            <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>

</configuration>
```

But its giving error: Unrecognized configuration section System.net/mailsettings.
What should changes i do?
Asp.net c#
Thank you.

Comment: Is the ending `</system.net>` tag present in the actual config file?

Comment: And do you have a smtp server running locally ?

Comment: Is it outside of the `<system.web>`-Section?

Comment: i have added that code after </configSections> before <system.web>

Comment: Try placing the `mailSettings` block at the end of the config file, just before the closing `</configuration>` tag.

Comment: config file means after </configSections> i did in that way only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this under the Configuration Section of your web.config file:

```
<system.net>
    <mailsettings>
      <smtp deliverymethod="Network" from="putFromEmail">
        <network host="localhost" port="25" defaultcredentials="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailsettings>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: i used posted code in web.config(After </configSections> & before <appSettings> but its giving error : Unrecognized configuration section System.net/mailsettings

Comment: you can edit your question and post your complete web.config. then I see, you must doing something wrong.

Comment: i have posted my web.config file

Comment: It seems to be fine.. can you put from email in smpt ?

Comment: From email in smtp means ? I have added mailmessage.from =emailid

Comment: Can you add this like what I have did in web.config

Comment: ya i have tried earlier also but its giving same problem in mailsettings

Comment: Can you add reference in your  website. System.Net --- on right click website and find system.net from .net tab

Comment: I am using .net 3.5 is their any problem with that version?

Comment: i added then also its giving same problem

Comment: did you add namespace in your page System.Net ?

Comment: now error comes as "Transport fails to connect to the server" in   SmtpMail.Send(mailMessage);

Comment: yes i have added System.net then also it doesnt connect to the server

Comment: yes, now the web.config issue resolve, now you are getting issue when you are trying to send an email local host. Hope it will work on server.

Comment: its giving error near smtp mail. why it doesnt connect to the smtp server

Comment: you have to set special configuration to send email from localhost. read this article carefully. you will understand your problem. now the problem in not in your web.config. but you need to set SMTP settings http://forums.asp.net/t/268037.aspx/1/10?SMTP+server+and+email+FAQ

Comment: happy to know that, can you share me what you have fixed ?

Comment: i have tried with host="smtp.gmail.com" & smtpclient with ssl enable as true and port=587 for gmail

Comment: can u see my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752717/how-to-check-whether-value-already-exists-or-not-in-database-when-inserting-new-r

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error "Unrecognized configuration section System.net/mailsettings" is because of the mis-spelling of `<mailSettings>` (you needed a capital S on Settings - xml is case-sensitive).

This tag in the web.config should appear as a direct child of the `<configuration> ...</configuration>` root element. Here is a simple snippet of code:

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
        <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyDevWebsite\aEmailPickupFolder" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

The official docs on this element of the web.config can be found on the [MSDN site here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w355a94k.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my mailer class:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Utils.Mailer
{
    public static class MailSender
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Sends a MailMessage object using the SMTP settings.
        /// </summary>
        public static void SendMailMessage(MailMessage message)
        {
            if (!Settings.Instance.SendEmails)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (message == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("message");

            try
            {
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                var smtp = new SmtpClient("myserver");

                // don't send credentials if a server doesn't require it,
                // linux smtp servers don't like that 
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty("myuser"))
                {
                    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myuser", "mypass");
                }
                smtp.Port = 25;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(message);
            }
            catch (SmtpException)
            {
                //OnEmailFailed(message);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Remove the pointer to the message object so the GC can close the thread.
                message.Dispose();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sends the mail message asynchronously in another thread.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message">The message to send.</param>
        public static void SendMailMessageAsync(MailMessage message)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => SendMailMessage(message));
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this feature/config section was added in .NET 2.0. Ensure your site's application pool is set to at least 2.0 framework. IIS >> Application Pools >> find the one assigned to your site, >> double click >> .net framework version.

from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w355a94k.aspx) (see dropdown at top, 1 is not listed)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string sendMail(string to, string title, string subject, string body)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                if (to == "")
                    to = "aevalencia119@gmail.com";
                MailAddressCollection m = new MailAddressCollection();
                m.Add(to);
                mail.Subject = subject;
                mail.From = new MailAddress( "aevalencia119@gmail.com");
                mail.Body = body;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mail.ReplyTo = new MailAddress("aevalencia119@gmail.com");
                mail.To.Add(m[0]);
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                 client.Port = 587;//25
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("aevalencia119@gmail.com", "####");
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; }; 

                smtp.Send(mail);

                return "done";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following link, may help u

[Send mail in asp.net](http://dotnetsparks.blogspot.com/2011/11/send-mail-in-aspnet.html)

Comment: please try to provide answers, as links may tend to expire.

Comment: Providing a code sample and a short description would ensure the usefulness of your post to future users. ;)