# how to give prompt message & after that redirecting page to another in button click event in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net

Hi 
I have one submit button to submit the page. When i click on submit button then it should give prompt message like "are you sure to submit that page really" if yes then it should redirect the another page.
I used code as follows:

```
RegisterStartupScript("myAlert", "<script>alert('Are you sure about to submit the test?')</script>");
Response.Redirect("Result.aspx");
```

But its directly redirecting the page without promting to user with message.
How its possible?
Asp.net c#

Comment: Give the message in the clientclick of button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do like..

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="javascript:return 
confirm('Are you sure about to submit the test?');" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

and then in code behind...

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Result.aspx");
}
```

Comment: its giving prompt message but when i click ok button then it should redirect to another page also

Comment: can u see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731001/how-to-send-mail-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

There's a modalpopup in Ajax Control Toolkit, maybe that would work for you?

Sample : http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Dont remember the exact syntax but you need to capture the clicked value and based on that you can do either a return true or a return false. True will submit the page