# How to check whether value already exists or not in database when inserting new record in sql server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have created a stored procedure for selecting value from the table if that value already exists then it will update that value but if not exists then it will insert new value.

I used stored procedure for that as follows :

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Insert]
(
    @Tid int = NULL,
    @Quid int = NULL,
    @Selected int = NULL,
    @Score int = NULL
)
AS
   DECLARE @AlreadyExisted BIT 
   SET @AlreadyExisted = 0  

   IF (EXISTS (SELECT Quid FROM  Sel_Ans) 
   BEGIN
      SET @AlreadyExisted = 1 

      UPDATE Sel_Ans
      SET Selected=@Selected
      WHERE Quid = @Quid 
   END 
   ELSE 
   BEGIN 
     INSERT INTO Sel_Ans (Quid, Selected) 
       VALUES (@Quid, @Selected)
   END
RETURN
```

And in C# (Asp.net) I used this code but its giving error "Error connecting to the database" as its going in try block. Suggest me any changes to my code to work correctly.

```
//session["Counter"] is my counter that will give next record in next click event
if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["Counter"]) <= 7)
{
   int t = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Counter"]);

   SqlCommand MyCmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Insert", sqlconn);
   MyCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   SqlParameter objParam1 = null;
   SqlParameter objParam2 = null;
   SqlParameter objParam3 = null;
   SqlParameter objParam4 = null;

   objParam1 = MyCmd.Parameters.Add("@Tid", SqlDbType.Int);
   objParam1.Value = '1';
   objParam2 = MyCmd.Parameters.Add("@Quid", SqlDbType.Int);
   objParam2.Value = a[t - 2];
   objParam3 = MyCmd.Parameters.Add("@Selected", SqlDbType.Int);
   objParam3.Value = rb;
   objParam4 = MyCmd.Parameters.Add("@Score", SqlDbType.Int);
   objParam4.Value = '1';

   try
   {
       if (sqlconn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
       {
          sqlconn.Open();
          MyCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Response.Write("Error Connecting to Database!");
   }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't hide the error in the catch block by outputting your own error message. For instance, in this case, you don't know if the error occurred during Open or ExecuteNonQuery. Instead you should Response.Write(ex.ToString()) - at least until all your issues are resolved. The error message in this case will give you enough context to figure out what is going on. 

Second point: you didn't show how sqlconn was instantiated. Please clarify that in the code. 

Third point: you can use MERGE to do INSERT/UDPATE together in a single statement.

Comment: how i can do merge statement here

Comment: 1. What does the error message in `ex` tell you? 2. The SP has a missing where clause in `if exists` query and one syntax error. 3. What version of SQL Server do you use? Merge can be used in SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are passing value to your stored procedure:

```
objParam1 = MyCmd.Parameters.Add("@Tid", SqlDbType.Int);
objParam1.Value = '1';
```

You are passing a string value (`'1'`).

You have to pass this as an integer, as your datatype in the sproc is `int`:

```
 objParam1.Value = 1;
```

do the same for the other parameter as well.

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT Quid FROM Sel_Ans where Quid = @Quid)
```

Comment: i did that but still values are not inserted in my Sel_Ans table

Comment: IF (EXISTS (SELECT Quid FROM  Sel_Ans where Quid = @Quid)

Comment: i tried with this also but same problem here not inserting values in table

Comment: in insert i have added all the fields & i changed sp like: if not exists then insert else update